# Rspec POST controller create test fails but web based submission works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I have the following rspec test for create method in my

```
describe "with valid information" do
  it "should respond with success" do
    post 'create', :show_secretary_id => @show_secretary.id, :show => @show
    response.should be_success
  end

  it "should incremenet the show count" do
    expect do 
      post 'create', :show_secretary_id => @show_secretary.id, :show => @show
    end.to change(Show,'count').by(1)
  end
end
```

The test fails. However, when I try the create method in the browser, it works. Any ideas on what I am missing?

EDIT: My Controller Code

```
  def create
    @show_secretary = ShowSecretary.find_by_id(params[:show_secretary_id])
    @show = @show_secretary.shows.build(params[:show])
    if @show.save
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully created show"
      redirect_to show_path @show 
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

EDIT: @show_secretary, @show

These two objects are ActiveRecords created and built by FactoryGirl respectively.

```
@show_secretary = FactoryGirl.create(:show_secretary_user).verifiable
@show = FactoryGirl.build(:show)
```

Comment: I posted an update with my controller code. Thank you for taking a look.

Comment: what does ```.verifiable``` do?

Comment: try to replace `@show = FactoryGirl.build(:show)` with `@show = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:show)`. Curious to have answer to @phoet question too.

Comment: ha, good eye. .verifiable returns the ShowSecretary object associated with that particular User (polymorphic association).

Comment: Of course! Create accepts a hash rather than an object. *face palm* Thank you so much!

Comment: Could you post the error Rspec is giving?

Comment: Are you using Devise? I run into this a lot where I don't use the Devise::TestHelper in my spec so the user is not signed in and can't access the action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
@show = FactoryGirl.build(:show)
```

with:

```
@show = FactoryGirl.attributes_for(:show)
```